# How to do raster data assimilation ( 3dVar ) in R or java?

Tags: java, r, raster

Assume that I have three raster images, lest say the following

1. raster 1

   [image]
2. raster 2

[image]

3. raster 3

[image]

4. Point (measurement)

[image]

So based on the data of the three raster images, I want to produce other prediction raster than minimise error at the measurement points (assuming the errors will also minimised at all over the raster).

or I want data assimilation of the three rasters (Assimilated raster=f(raster1,raster2,raster3) that minimise errors at measurement points).

Could you please suggest for any package  (or codes) that can do this operation in R, or java ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you well, you want to do a supervised classification, where you have three predictor variables (rasters) and a few observations (points) for which you have a measurement. Here is an example of how you can do that:

```
library(raster)
library(dismo)
# three layers
logo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
logo

# 10 random points
set.seed(0)
p <- randomPoints(logo, 10)

# extract values for points
pv <- extract(logo, p)

# observations at those locations
obs <- apply(pv + rnorm(length(pv), 0, 100), 1, sum)

v <- data.frame(obs=obs, pv)

# fit a model
model <- glm(formula=obs~., data=v)
model

# predict
r <- predict(logo, model, progress='text')

plot(r)
points(p, pch=20, col='red')
```

You may want to replace `glm` with another, more flexible, method such as RandomForest. see `?raster::predict` for more examples and also see this vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/vignettes/sdm.pdf.
The context may be different but the general approach (supervised classification) very similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for a Python package which provides the 3DVAR data assimilation algorithm, you may consider OpenTURNS and the `GaussianNonLinearCalibration` class:

http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/user_manual/_generated/openturns.GaussianNonLinearCalibration.html